# Metric Space and Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question that I am struggling to solve.

Let $(X;d)$ be any discrete metric space and let ${x_n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X;d)$. Show that there exists $k\in N$ such that $x_n=x_k$ for all $n≥k$.

I was attempting to use the fact that Cauchy sequences are bounded.but still, I am not sure how to go about answering this question.

Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you have mistaken the question :). The sequence $(1/n)$ is Cauchy in the metric space $\mathbb{R}$; but no two components of the sequence are the same.

Comment: Possibly $(X,d)$ is discrete...

Comment: Yes $ (X,d)$ discrete

Comment: You should edit your question and add that crucial assumption.

Comment: Furthermore you should add the definition of discrete. The topological definition of discrete will be too weak, since the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the discrete space $\{\frac{1}{n}, n \geq 1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a comment but I am too poor to comment. :(

If you use the discrete metric, then this follows easily by taking $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$.

The sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy, so there exists $k$ such that $|x_n - x_m| \leq \epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n,m \geq k$. But $|x_n - x_m| < 1 \Longrightarrow |x_n - x_m| = 0$ in the discrete metric, so $x_n = x_m$.

If $x_n \to x$, you might also consider the neighborhood of $x$ which is just $\{x\}$ (it is open in the discrete topology). This neighborhood must contain all but finitely many elements of $(x_n)$.